# Void value not ignored as it ought to be (Trying to assign void to non-void variable?)

Tags: c++

```
vector<vector<int>> matrixReshape(vector<vector<int>>& nums, int r, int c) {
        int row = nums.size();
        int col = nums[0].size();
        vector<vector<int>> newNums;
        if((row*col) < (r*c)){
            return nums;
        }
        else{
            deque<int> storage;
            for(int i = 0; i < row; i++){
                for(int k = 0; k < col; k++){
                    storage.push_back(nums[i][k]);
                }
            }
            for(int j = 0; j < r; j++){
                for(int l = 0; l < c; l++){
                    newNums[j][l] = storage.pop_front();
                }
            }
        }
        return newNums;
    }
```

Hey guys, I am having a problem where I am getting the said error of the title above 'Void value not ignored as it ought to be'. When I looked up the error message, the tips stated **"This is a GCC error message that means the return-value of a function is 'void', but that you are trying to assign it to a non-void variable. You aren't allowed to assign void to integers, or any other type."** After reading this, I assumed my deque was not being populated; however, I can not find out why my deque is not being populated. If you guys would like to know the problem I am trying to solve, I will be posting it below. Also, I cannot run this through a debugger since it will not compile :(. Thanks in advance.

> In MATLAB, there is a very useful function called 'reshape', which can reshape a matrix into a new one with different size but keep its original data.
>
> You're given a matrix represented by a two-dimensional array, and two positive integers r and c representing the row number and column number of the wanted reshaped matrix, respectively.
>
> The reshaped matrix need to be filled with all the elements of the original matrix in the same row-traversing order as they were.
>
> If the 'reshape' operation with given parameters is possible and legal, output the new reshaped matrix; Otherwise, output the original matrix.
>
> ```
>    Example 1:
>     Input: 
>     nums = 
>     [[1,2],
>      [3,4]]
>     r = 1, c = 4
>     Output: 
>     [[1,2,3,4]]
>     Explanation:
>     The row-traversing of nums is [1,2,3,4]. The new reshaped matrix is a 1 * 4 matrix, fill it row by row by using the previous list.
> ```

Comment: Reading some docs never hurts https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/deque/pop_front

Comment: `pop_front()` doesn't return the element that was removed from the vector, so you can't assign it to `newNums[j][l]`

Answer (score 0):

This line has two problems:

```
newNums[j][l] = storage.pop_front();
```

First, `pop_front()` doesn't return the element that was popped. To get the first element of the deque, use `storage[0]`. Then call `pop_front()` to remove it.

You also can't assign to `newNums[j][i]`, because you haven't allocated those elements of the vectors. You can pre-allocate all the memory by declaring it like this.

```
vector<vector<int>> newNums(r, vector<int>(c));
```

So the above line should be replaced with:

```
newNums[j][l] = storage[0];
storage.pop_front();
```

Comment: What do you mean that I have not allocated those elements of the vector? Are they not empty because I have not set them yet? And ahh, I see pop_front does not return the value, but just removes the element from the list. Would I be able to avoid referring to the position of something with a stack? Because this would cause problems within my for loop because the size of the deque is not the same as the size of the loop constraint and therefore I would not completely search through the deque.

Comment: Declaring a vector doesn't create any elements in the vector unless you specify the initial size in the declaration. Vector elements cannot be created with subscript assignment.

Comment: I haven't actually read the problem statement, so I don't know if your overall algorithm is correct. Your loop doesn't try to search the deque completely, it just puts the first `r*c` elements into `newNums`.

Comment: The explanation of `reshape` doesn't say what should happen with the extra elements if `row * col != r * c`. It seems like your code is as correct as can be.

Comment: You might also want to read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1262808/which-stl-container-should-i-use-for-a-fifo). It recommends using `std::queue` rather than `std::deque` for this.

Comment: Hey Barmar, I ended up using a stack. Here is a link to my code if you would like to check it out. Thank you for the help. Leetcode Link : https://leetcode.com/problems/reshape-the-matrix/discuss/143430/C++-Solution-Easy-to-Understand-Beats-65

Comment: A stack seems wrong for this, it returns the elements in the opposite order that they were inserted. A queue returns them in the same order.

Comment: Yeah, afterwards I read that, I see that a queue would be better. Thank you for your help!